# Firebase Admin Java SDK ValueEventListener not working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-admin

I did an android client application using Firebase, it's working well. I want to do an admit application, but I got an issue. it looks like there are threads with the same issue, but the solution did not work for me.

I'm following the doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup

Then I created a brand new project (this project do not have client library and won't have). 
I added

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:4.1.3'
```

First, I got this error

```
Error:Conflict with dependency 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305' in project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (1.3.9) and test app (2.0.1) differ. See http://g.co/androidstudio/app-test-app-conflict for details.
```

After investigation, I found

[Error:Conflict with dependency 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37347326/errorconflict-with-dependency-com-google-code-findbugsjsr305).

The solution is to add

```
 configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
}
```

It's working, but I still got some warning.

```
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.json:json:20160212 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.json:json:20160212 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.json:json:20160212 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
```

I can live with that, then I continue.

I create my admin key and downloaded the file. In the doc, they ask us to do this code:

```
FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json");
```

But I did not found where to put the file to make it work (obviously with the right folder name and file name). After some investigation, I found I can place the file in

```
res/raw/serviceAccountKey.json
```

and creating a FileInputStream like this

```
InputStream serviceAccount = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.serviceAccountKey);
```

Perfect. Seems to work, then the code look like this

```
    InputStream serviceAccount = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.serviceAccountKey);
    FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setCredential(FirebaseCredentials.fromCertificate(serviceAccount))
            .setDatabaseUrl("https://" + m_databaseName + ".firebaseio.com/")
            .build();
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
```

For now, I don't have any error. then I do the next step

```
    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            System.out.println("The read succeed");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
        }
    });
```

But, onDataChange and onCancelled are never called. I don't see any error.

After investigation, I found others with the same issue

[Firebase Admin Java SDK not doing any operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42222423/firebase-admin-java-sdk-not-doing-any-operation)

But the solution did not work.

have Anyone an idea? Thanks

Comment: Firebase engineers advise against using the Admin SDK in an Android app.  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42103063/4815718

Comment: This Answer is 

    "You can't use the Firebase Admin SDK in an Android app alongside the Firebase Android client libraries."

But this is not my case. I'm not adding Admin sdk in a client app. I'm creating a brand new app with only the admit sdk

Comment: Ok, I found this too
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42163212/firebase-admin-sdk-causes-gradle-dependency-error?noredirect=1&lq=1

Look like you are right and I cannot do an admin app in android. Ok, then I'm trying eclipse to do an admin app. but I do no find any Build.Gradle file in my eclipse project to add the 

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:4.1.3'

Where am I supposed to add this in my eclipse project if I only see the build.gradle in my android project

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found the problem. 
Like "qbix" comment, Firebase admin can not be done in android.

I usually work in c++ and java/gradle/android is totally new to me. I did not know "gradle" was not just a file in Android studio.

Then if you are like me and you are new in android/firebase/java and did the same mistake than I did, there is a to make it work.

Installed Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers
https://eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/

add Gradle support to eclipse
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseGradle/article.html

Create a new project. (Use tutorial from Eclipse)

Redo the firebase tutorial for firebase from firebase tutorial

and now I finally reach my breakpoint in onDataChange and the data seems right